# This case is too/fairly heavy, but I can still lift it. Which is better?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This case is too/fairly heavy, but I can still lift it. Which is better, ‘too’ or ‘fairly’ ?

Answer (score 1):

If it is too heavy for some other constraint, you need to specify, unless it is clear from previous context:

> This case is too heavy for that shelf (I can put it up, but the shelf will break if I do)
>
> This case is too heavy for my mother to lift (but I am stronger)
>
> This case is too heavy to carry for a long distance (but I can lift it briefly)

Otherwise, *too heavy for me to lift* is the only reasonably implied meaning, and that's obviously impossible.

Comment: In my sentence, **too** is better, or **fairly**?

Comment: (You have changed the question.)  *Fairly* is fine.